# API to return value in PHP

Tags: php, api

Have been using this example on an API to create a group.

```
  $response = $soap->createGroup(

 array(

 'api_key'=> $api_key,
 'group_name'=> 'Fred'
 )

);
```

and this works well.  However.  I need to get the API to return the group ID.  The API says the following

```
createGroup
- Usage: Used to create a group that a recipient can be placed in.
- Return: The id of the created group, used in such functions as addRecipient
- Parameters
o group_name (required), your reference to the group, e.g. ‘Group 1’
o add_recipients (optional), the id or an array of existing recipient ids to add to this group, see 
addRecipient
```

How can I do this in PHP so that I can add the necessary recipients to this group, as when trying to add recipient the following is needed.

```
addRecipient
- Usage: Used to add a recipient to your account
- Return: The id of the added recipient
- Parameters
o email (required), the recipients email address
o name (optional), the recipient's name
o group (optional), id of an existing group, see createGroup.
```

which needs the group ID, not the name.

Many thanks for your help as this has been bugging me.

Louk

Comment: What does `$response` look like? The group ID should be in that.

Comment: I Try and echo it and get this 'Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /var/www/vhosts/icanpromo.co.uk/httpdocs/API/Add.php on line 31'

Comment: use print_r($response) instead

Comment: That returns the value of the group but I can't use it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're working with the [Audiolock API](http://www.audiolock.net/developers).

Get the group ID from the response to your `createGroup` query, and then use that value in the `addRecipient` query:

```
# $response is the response from your createGroup query
$addRecipResponse = $soap->AddRecipient(
    'email' => 'me@home.com',
    'group' => $response,
    'api_key' => $api_key  ## may be needed, may not be
);
# the response is the ID of the recipient
$recip_id = $addRecipResponse($response->response);
```

Comment: Sadly that still does not work....  it inserts the recipients but doesnt add them to the group.

Comment: changed 'group' => $gid, to 'group' => $response, and it worked!  Nice one!!